# Power usage NVIDIA on Juno

Tags: nvidia, power, battery

I noticed that after upgrading from Loki to Juno my battery life was severally decreased. 
I have a Dell XPS 9550 with a NVIDI GeForce(R) GTX 960M.

- I've installed `tlp` and `tlp-rdw`
- I've addded the nvidia graphics drivers ppa: `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`.
- I'm using nvidia-driver-...
- I've installed all the recent updates
- I've switched to `intel` using `prime-select`.

I noticed however when checking powertop Tunables, when running from battery the following item:

```
Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
```

I also noticed:

```
The battery reports a discharge rate of 20.9 W
```

When I switched the NVIDIA item from bad to good I got:

```
The battery reports a discharge rate of 12.4 W
```

Which is quite a significant drop.

I found this possible related question, but the issue seems solved and should have been back-ported to Ubuntu 18.04 already.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037977/optimus-nvidia-gpu-turned-on-whatever-prime-select-says/1045767?noredirect=1#comment1799551_1045767

Questions:

- Why would the NVIDIA card still use power even though I selected Intel?
- Is there a better way to disable it?
- Is there an easy way to make this powertop tune permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: Augustin found a better approach for using a SystemD service:**

One option to make this powertop tune permanent:

1. Copy the command powertop executes when switching the nvidia tunable from bad to good. In my case that was:
   `/bin/echo auto > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0/power/control`
2. Add a SystemD service that executes that command: create:
   `/etc/systemd/system/nvidia-power-control.service`
3. Fill with:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=NVIDIA automatic power control
   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/bin/echo auto > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0/power/control'
   KillMode=none
   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

   Make sure the command inside the `/bin/sh -c ''` is the copied command.
4. Run: `systemctl daemon-reload`.
5. Run: `systemctl enable nvidia-power-control`.
6. Run: `systemctl start nvidia-power-control`.
7. Verify it's running:

   ```
   $ systemctl status nvidia-power-control
   ● nvidia-power-control.service - NVIDIA automatic power control
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nvidia-power-control.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
      Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2018-11-29 14:21:20 CET; 6s ago
     Process: 28759 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c /bin/echo auto > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0/power/control (code=exited, status=0/S
    Main PID: 28759 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

   nov 29 14:21:20 xps systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA automatic power control...
   nov 29 
   14:21:20 xps systemd[1]: Started NVIDIA automatic power control.
   ```

For me this made sure the powertop tunables always indicates good for the Nvidia card.

Please tell me if there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: pretty cool, your workaround is very easy now.

Comment: instead of using /usr/local/bin/powertop-tuning i recommend to use /opt and then add the PATH or create a soft link in /usr/local/bin/ or w/e

Answer (score 0):

I would like to provide alternative way to make PowerTop tune permanent.

**// According to Ubuntu ManPage rc.local is now provided for backward compatibility and shouldn't be used unless it's not necessary.**

**// A proper way is probably to use a particular unit file. See Peter's answer.**

Also **/etc/rc.local** can be used to achieve this.
When this file exists it's being executed automatically during late boot.

For more info about rc.local see:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/systemd-rc-local-generator.8.html

**1. Create /etc/rc.local file**

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

**2. Write the script**

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

echo auto > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control

exit 0
```

Source: https://hastebin.com/yurufehezi.bash

**3. Make it executable**

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

**4. Reboot your machine**

After that systemd rc-local.service is available and loaded:

```
$ systemctl status rc-local.service 
● rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; enabled-runtime; vendo
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
           └─debian.conf
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2018-11-27 14:36:30 CET; 1 day 7h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-rc-local-generator(8)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rc-local.service

lis 27 14:36:30 elementaryNix systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
lis 27 14:36:30 elementaryNix rc.local[1229]: Enabled persistence mode for GPU 
lis 27 14:36:30 elementaryNix rc.local[1229]: All done.
lis 27 14:36:30 elementaryNix systemd[1]: Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
```